# template class to manage containers, getting type of contained data

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated c++ class which acts on containers. In the class implementation I need access to the type of the data the container contains. I've currently defined it like this:

```
template <typename ContainerType, typename DataType>
class MyClass {
    DataType a;
    DataType foo(DataVector& vec, DataType s);
};
```

And when I instantiate it I instantiate it like this

```
MyClass< vector<float>, float > c1;
MyClass< CustomVector<double>, double > c2;
MyClass< Lib::ContainerFloat, Lib::Float > c3;
```

This works, but is there a way of doing this without duplicating the type info (i.e. float, double etc)? I.e. use some decltype-like magic to get the contained data type. So I'd like to be able to instantiate with:

```
MyClass< vector<float> > c1;
MyClass< CustomVector<double> > c2;
MyClass< Lib::ContainerFloat > c3;
```

and declare the class with:

```
template <typename ContainerType>
class MyClass {
    // get DataType automatically from ContainerType
    DataType a;
    DataType foo(DataVector& vec, DataType s);
};
```

Comment: Don't get your question. You can write `DataType var = vector[0];`, isn't it?

Comment: my question is how I can avoid duplicating information regarding the datatype. I.e. not declare it but extract from the container, since it's known at compile time. I've edited my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a concept, all containers are expected to support `value_type` as a type. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container.

Last I checked, `value_type` is supported by:

1. `std::vector`
2. `std::list`
3. `std::set`
4. `std::multiset`
5. `std::unordered_set`
6. `std::queue`
7. `std::array`
8. `std::map`
9. `std::unordered_map`
10. `std::multimap`
11. `std::stack`
12. `std::priority_queue`

I think it's safe for you to use:

```
template <typename ContainerType>
class MyClass {
   using DataType = ContainerType::value_type;
};

MyClass< vector<float>> c1;
```

If `DataType` can ever be different than `ContainerType::value_type`, it will be better to use (Thanks are due to @AlexeyAndronov for the suggestion):

```
template <typename ContainerType,
          typename DataType = ContainerType::value_type>
class MyClass {
};
```

Comment: or more beautiful: `template <class ContainerType, class DataType = typename ContainerType::value_type>
class MyClass {};`

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov, nice suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using an standard library container template, each such template  defines a definition for its value type. It's a good practice to do so in your own custom containers as well.

Given this definition is available, this pattern should cover the use case you describe.

```
template<class container>
class MyClass{
public:
    typename container::value_type a;
};
```